# How to create a pyo-only distribution?

Tags: python-3.x, bytecode

I was inspired by [this article](http://www.curiousefficiency.org/posts/2011/04/benefits-and-limitations-of-pyc-only.html) as I think about obfuscation and reducing the storage requirements of my python app for an embedded device.  I compileall from the command line and then remove all *.py files.

My app has many modules (subdirectories with `__init__.py` files), and I'm having issues simply stripping away all of the `.py` source files.  If I remove all the py source files, I get import errors.  I experimented with only stripping out .py source files that are not the `__init__.py` files and still get import errors.  The pycache directory also contains both *.pyc (interpreter-generated) and *.pyo (compileall-generated) files.  **Do I only need one type?**

I've tested compileall with and without the legacy `-b` option but still get the same import errors for a file that understandably no longer exists.

```
from mypackage.mypyfile import my_main
```

Is there more of a standard procedure for creating a pyo-only distribution?

```
# Clean potentially pre-existing cache
find mydir -type f -name "*.py[co]" -delete
find mydir -type d -name "__pycache__" -exec rm -r "{}" +
sync

# Byte-compile, ignoring .git subdirectories
python3 -m compileall -b -f -x r'[/\\][.]git' mydir

# Remove all source files
find mydir -type f -name "*.py" -delete
```

related: [Is there a way to combine a python project codebase that spans across different files into one file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18199290/is-there-a-way-to-combine-a-python-project-codebase-that-spans-across-different)

Comment: What device are you targeting? Have you determined the total storage requirements of the app? How does that compare to the size of the source files? It's a rare app where source files are a non-negligible fraction of the total size.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the pyo-only distribution must be invoked with the same interpreter and interpreter flags as those used to byte-compile:

```
python3 -OO myapp.py
```

http://bugs.python.org/issue570640